# twisted: catch keyboardinterrupt and shutdown properly

Tags: python, twisted, shutdown

UPDATE: For ease of reading, here is how to add a callback before the reactor gets shutdown:

```
reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('before', 'shutdown', callable)
```

Original question follows.

---

If I have a client connected to a server, and it's chilling in the reactor main loop waiting for events, when I hit CTRL-C, I get a "Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost." How can I set it up so that I know when a KeyboardInterrupt happens, so that I can do proper clean-up and disconnect cleanly? Or how can I implement a cleaner way to shutdown that doesn't involve CTRL-C, if possible?

Comment: sweet, first hit on googling "twisted before shutdown"!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you really, really want to catch C-c specifically, then you can do this in the usual way for a Python application - use `signal.signal` to install a handler for `SIGINT` that does whatever you want to do.  If you invoke any Twisted APIs from the handler, make sure you use `reactor.callFromThread` since almost all other Twisted APIs are unsafe for invocation from signal handlers.

However, if you're really just interested in inserting some shutdown-time cleanup code, then you probably want to use `IService.stopService` (or the mechanism in terms of which it is implemented,`reactor.addSystemEventTrigger`) instead.

If you're using `twistd`, then using `IService.stopService` is easy.  You already have an `Application` object with at least one service attached to it.  You can add another one with a custom `stopService` method that does your shutdown work.  The method is allowed to return a `Deferred`.  If it does, then the shutdown process is paused until that `Deferred` fires.  This lets you clean up your connections nicely, even if that involves some more network (or any other asynchronous) operations.

If you're not using `twistd`, then using `reactor.addSystemEventTrigger` directly is probably easier.  You can install a *before shutdown* trigger which will get called in the same circumstance `IService.stopService` would have been called.  This trigger (just any callable object) can also return a `Deferred` to delay shutdown.  This is done with a call to `reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('before', 'shutdown', callable)` (sometime before shutdown is initiated, so that it's already registered whenever shutdown does happen).

[service.tac](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/%5Fdownloads/service.tac) gives an example of creating and using a custom service.

[wxacceptance.py](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/%5Fdownloads/wxacceptance.py) gives an example of using `addSystemEventTrigger` and delaying shutdown by (an arbitrary) three seconds.

Both of these mechanisms will give you notification *whenever* the reactor is stopping.  This may be due to a C-c keystroke, or it may be because someone used `kill -INT ...`, or it may be because somewhere `reactor.stop()` was called.  They all lead to reactor shutdown, and reactor shutdown always processes shutdown event triggers.

Comment: perfect! worked just as i liked. now after months of having ugly cleanup it's finally nice and pretty...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether you talking about a client or a server that you've written.

Anyway, nothing wrong with 'CTRL-C'.

If you're writing a server as an Application. Subclass from `twisted.application.service.Service` and define `startService` and `stopService`. Maintain a list of active protocol instances. Use `stopService` to go through them and close them gracefully.

If you've got a client, you could also subclass `Service`, but it could be simpler to use `reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('before','shutdown',myCleanUpFunction)`, and close connection(s) gracefully in this function.