# How do I add an errback to deferLater?

Tags: python, twisted

Consider the following twisted code, using deferLater:

```
import random

from twisted.internet.task import deferLater
from twisted.internet import reactor

def random_exception(msg='general'):
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        raise Exception("Random exception with 50%% likelihood occurred in %s!" % msg)

def dolater():
    random_exception('dolater')
    print "it's later!"

def whoops(failure):
    failure.trap(Exception)
    print failure

defer = deferLater(reactor, 10, dolater)
defer.addErrback(whoops)

reactor.run()
```

An exception is raised during the 10 second sleep (namely a <del>`KeyboardInterrupt`</del>), however, it seems that the `whoops` method is never called. My assumption is that since I add the errBack after the deferred kicks off, it's never properly registered. Advice appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Alright, no one likes my use of the signal (not the exception) `KeyboardInterrupt` to show an error condition outside of the defer. I thought pretty hard about an actual exception that might occur out of the defer callback, but couldn't think of a particularly good one, most everything would be some kind of signal (or developer error), so signal handling is fine for now- but that wasn't really the heart of the question.

As I understand it, twisted's callback/errback system handles errors within the callback structure - e.g. if `dolater` raises an Exception of some kind. To show this, I have added an exception that could occur during `dolater`, to show that if the exception occurs in `dolater`, the errback handles the exception just fine.

My concern was if something went wrong while the reactor was just reacting normally, and the only thing I could get to go wrong was a keyboard interrupt, then I wanted whoops to fire. It appears that if I put other async events into the reactor and raise exceptions from there, then the dolater code wouldn't be affected, and I would have to add errbacks to those other async events. There is no master error handling for an entire twisted program.

So signals it is, until I can find some way to cause the reactor to fail without a signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by `KeyboardInterrupt` you mean a signal (`ctrl-c`, `SIGINT`, etc), then what you need to do is setup a signal handler with your `whoops` function as the callback.

By following two previous answers from @jean-paul-calderone [twisted: catch keyboardinterrupt and shutdown properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3453986/3334178) and [twisted - interrupt callback via KeyboardInterrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126412/3334178), I tried the following, and I think it matches your need:

```
def dolater():
    print "it's later!"

def whoops(signal, stackframe):
    print "I'm here because of signal number " + str(signal)
    reactor.stop()

defer = task.deferLater(reactor, 10, dolater)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, whoops)
reactor.run()
```

That will call whoops on a `SIGINT`.  I put a reactor.stop() in the whoops because otherwise the reactor would just keep on running, take that out if you really want it to keep running in the face of a `ctrl-c`.

Note: I'm not explicitly showing how to fire a err-back in the signal system because (at least to my understanding) that doesn't really map to how defer'ed should be used.  I imagine if you found a way to get the defer'ed into the signal handler you could `fire` its errback but I think thats out of the expected use-case for twisted and may have crazy consequences.

Comment: @bbengfort you asked about an `exception` happening while twisted waits. A signal is the only way I can imagine that happening, if `exception` means something other then `signal` in the context of your question then explain more

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the actual exception you're trying to catch, specifically `KeyboardInterrupt` is not a subclass of `Exception`, thus can not be catched with it. If you'd just change the line:

```
failure.trap(Exception)
```

into:

```
failure.trap(KeyboardInterrupt)
```

it surely would catch it. More on Python's exception hierarchy can be found in the official Python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html

Comment: Well, that's certainly a good thought- and you're right a KeyboardInterrupt is not a subclass of Exception; unfortunately when I tried it, I didn't get the desired result (e.g. the Errback is simply not firing- it has nothing to do with the trap).

Answer (score 0):

Twisted is a library for doing many things concurrently.  The things are kept as isolated as possible (given that this is still Python, there's still global state, etc).

If you have a TCP server with two clients connect to it and one of them sends you some bad data that triggers a bug in your parser that leads to an exception being raised, that exception isn't going to cause the *other* client to receive any error.  Nor would you want it to, I hope (at least not automatically).

Similarly, if you have a client connected to your server and you start a delayed call with `deferLater` and the client triggers that bug, you wouldn't want the error to be delivered to the errback on the `Deferred` returned by `deferLater`.

The idea here is that separate event sources are generally treated separately (until *you* write some code that glues them together somehow).

For the ten seconds that are passing between when you call `deferLater` and when Twisted begins to run the function you passed to `deferLater`, any errors that happen - including you hitting C-c on your keyboard to make Python raise a KeyboardInterrupt - aren't associated with that delayed call and they won't be delivered to the errback you attach to its `Deferred`.

Only exceptions raised by your `dolater` function will cause the errback chain of that `Deferred` to begin execution.

Comment: So, while that does make perfect sense- it doesn't offer me a solution. Where should I do the error handling if not in the deferred?

Comment: By "error handling" do you mean "handle the user hitting Control-C"?